# Circles detection with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am currently facing an issue with a program I have developed. The program is designed to read an image file containing an annulus and identify both the circle inside the annulus and the one outside. Furthermore, it is intended to scan the inner circle similar to a sonar and detect any imperfections within it. However, I am encountering a problem where the program fails to detect the circle inside the annulus. I have attempted adjusting various parameters, but none of these modifications have proven effective. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to address this issue.[text]

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_annulus(image):
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Denoise the image
    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, 10, 10, 7)

    # Perform Canny edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(denoised, 50, 100)

    # Detect circles using Hough Circle Transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=50, param1=50, param2=25, minRadius=220,
                               maxRadius=1000)

    # Check if circles are found
    if circles is not None:
        # Convert the circle parameters to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)

        # Filter circles based on size, aspect ratio, or position if needed

        # Sort circles by radius in descending order
        circles = sorted(circles, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

        # Extract the annulus circle (outer circle)
        x, y, r_outer = circles[0]

        # Extract the inside circle (smaller circle)
        x_inner, y_inner, r_inner = circles[1]

        # Calculate the radius inside the annulus
        r_final = r_outer - r_inner

        # Draw the circles on the image
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), r_outer, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(image, (x_inner, y_inner), r_inner, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Display the image with circles
        cv2.imshow('Circles', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        return r_final
    else:
        print("No circles detected.")
        return None

def scan_circle_for_imperfections(image, center_x, center_y, radius, step_size):
    # Initialize variables to store imperfections
    imperfections = []

    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Calculate the number of iterations based on step size
    num_iterations = int(360 / step_size)

    # Initialize variables to store the largest and smallest r_final values
    largest_r_final = None
    smallest_r_final = None

    # Iterate over angles around the circle
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Compute the current angle
        angle = i * step_size

        # Compute the coordinates of the point on the circle
        x = int(center_x + radius * np.cos(np.radians(angle)))
        y = int(center_y + radius * np.sin(np.radians(angle)))

        # Get the pixel intensity at the point
        intensity = gray[y, x]

        # Calculate the r_final value at the current point
        r_final = intensity / 255.0 * radius

        # Update the largest and smallest r_final values
        if largest_r_final is None or r_final > largest_r_final:
            largest_r_final = r_final
        if smallest_r_final is None or r_final < smallest_r_final:
            smallest_r_final = r_final

    # Calculate the threshold for detecting imperfections
    threshold = 0.5  # Adjust this value based on your requirements

    # Iterate over angles again to find imperfections
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Compute the current angle
        angle = i * step_size

        # Compute the coordinates of the point on the circle
        x = int(center_x + radius * np.cos(np.radians(angle)))
        y = int(center_y + radius * np.sin(np.radians(angle)))

        # Get the pixel intensity at the point
        intensity = gray[y, x]

        # Calculate the r_final value at the current point
        r_final = intensity / 255.0 * radius

        # Check if the r_final value is significantly larger than others
        if r_final - smallest_r_final > threshold * (largest_r_final - smallest_r_final):
            imperfections.append((x, y))

    return imperfections

def main():
    # Load the input image
    image = cv2.imread('Images/1.jpg')

    # Detect the annulus and calculate the inside and outside radii
    r_final = detect_annulus(image)

    if r_final is not None:
        # Find the center coordinates of the annulus
        center_x = int(image.shape[1] / 2)
        center_y = int(image.shape[0] / 2)

        # Define the scanning radius from the center
        scan_radius = int(r_final * 1.2)

        # Define the step size for scanning
        step_size = 5

        # Scan the circle for imperfections
        imperfections = scan_circle_for_imperfections(image, center_x, center_y, scan_radius, step_size)

        # Print the imperfections
        if imperfections:
            print(f"Imperfections found: {len(imperfections)}")
            for imperfection in imperfections:
                print(f"Coordinate: {imperfection}")
        else:
            print("No imperfections found.")
    else:
        print("Failed to detect the annulus.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the image i used is :[Annulus Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz8q8.jpg)

Comment: for optical inspection/machine vision, you should approach this like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8OiR.png (1) bounding box for center estimate (2) sample along rays to get points on the edges (3) fit ellipses (4) polar to cartesian transform to ***unroll*** the thing. then you'll have straight lines for the edges, and anything deviating would stand out. -- if that image looks useful to you, I could write an answer about it.

Comment: please provide a picture of "imperfections" as well

Comment: @NisipeanuIonut Can you please respond my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the outer circle and the inner circle have the same center coordinate, but `minDist` parameter limits the minimum distance between the centers.

> **minDist** - Minimum distance between the centers of the detected circles. If the parameter is too small, multiple neighbor circles may be falsely detected in addition to a true one. If it is too large, some circles may be missed.

In general [cv2.HoughCircles](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) is not designed to detect multiple circles with the same center coordinate.

We may find the outer and inner circles in two iterations:

- Use `cv2.HoughCircles` for finding the outer circle (ignore the inner circle).
- Erase the outer circle from `edges` (draw black color over the outer circle).
- Use `cv2.HoughCircles` for finding the inner circle.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_annulus(image):
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Denoise the image
    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, 10, 10, 7)

    # Perform Canny edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(denoised, 50, 100)

    # Detect circles using Hough Circle Transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=50, param1=50, param2=25, minRadius=220, 
                               maxRadius=1000)

    # Check if circles are found
    if circles is not None:
        # Convert the circle parameters to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)

        # Filter circles based on size, aspect ratio, or position if needed

        # Sort circles by radius in descending order
        circles = sorted(circles, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

        # Extract the annulus circle (outer circle)
        x, y, r_outer = circles[0]

        # Draw the circles on the image
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), r_outer, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        #cv2.circle(image, (x_inner, y_inner), r_inner, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Erase the outer (large) circle.
        cv2.circle(edges, (x, y), r_outer, 0, 5)

        #cv2.imshow('edges', edges)


        # Detect circles using Hough Circle Transform (detect the inner circle).
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=50, param1=50, param2=25, minRadius=220, 
                                maxRadius=300)        

        if circles is not None:
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)

            # Sort circles by radius in descending order
            circles = sorted(circles, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

            # Extract the inside circle (smaller circle)
            x_inner, y_inner, r_inner = circles[0]

            cv2.circle(image, (x_inner, y_inner), r_inner, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Calculate the radius inside the annulus
            r_final = r_outer - r_inner
        else:
            print("No Inner circle detected.")
            return None



        # Display the image with circles
        cv2.imshow('Circles', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        #cv2.imwrite('circles_image.png', image)

        return r_final
    else:
        print("No circles detected.")
        return None


def scan_circle_for_imperfections(image, center_x, center_y, radius, step_size):
    # Initialize variables to store imperfections
    imperfections = []

    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Calculate the number of iterations based on step size
    num_iterations = int(360 / step_size)

    # Initialize variables to store the largest and smallest r_final values
    largest_r_final = None
    smallest_r_final = None

    # Iterate over angles around the circle
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Compute the current angle
        angle = i * step_size

        # Compute the coordinates of the point on the circle
        x = int(center_x + radius * np.cos(np.radians(angle)))
        y = int(center_y + radius * np.sin(np.radians(angle)))

        # Get the pixel intensity at the point
        intensity = gray[y, x]

        # Calculate the r_final value at the current point
        r_final = intensity / 255.0 * radius

        # Update the largest and smallest r_final values
        if largest_r_final is None or r_final > largest_r_final:
            largest_r_final = r_final
        if smallest_r_final is None or r_final < smallest_r_final:
            smallest_r_final = r_final

    # Calculate the threshold for detecting imperfections
    threshold = 0.5  # Adjust this value based on your requirements

    # Iterate over angles again to find imperfections
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Compute the current angle
        angle = i * step_size

        # Compute the coordinates of the point on the circle
        x = int(center_x + radius * np.cos(np.radians(angle)))
        y = int(center_y + radius * np.sin(np.radians(angle)))

        # Get the pixel intensity at the point
        intensity = gray[y, x]

        # Calculate the r_final value at the current point
        r_final = intensity / 255.0 * radius

        # Check if the r_final value is significantly larger than others
        if r_final - smallest_r_final > threshold * (largest_r_final - smallest_r_final):
            imperfections.append((x, y))

    return imperfections

def main():
    # Load the input image
    image = cv2.imread('Images/1.jpg')

    # Detect the annulus and calculate the inside and outside radii
    r_final = detect_annulus(image)

    if r_final is not None:
        # Find the center coordinates of the annulus
        center_x = int(image.shape[1] / 2)
        center_y = int(image.shape[0] / 2)

        # Define the scanning radius from the center
        scan_radius = int(r_final * 1.2)

        # Define the step size for scanning
        step_size = 5

        # Scan the circle for imperfections
        imperfections = scan_circle_for_imperfections(image, center_x, center_y, scan_radius, step_size)

        # Print the imperfections
        if imperfections:
            print(f"Imperfections found: {len(imperfections)}")
            for imperfection in imperfections:
                print(f"Coordinate: {imperfection}")
        else:
            print("No imperfections found.")
    else:
        print("Failed to detect the annulus.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:
[image]

---

Note:
In general, `cv2.HoughCircles` is not a robust method for finding circles.
Using `cv2.threshold` (with `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`), and then `cv2.findContours` (without `cv2.Canny`) is much more robust way for finding the contours of the circles.
We may use `cv2.minEnclosingCircle` for finding the center and the radius of the contours.
We may also use two stages (finding the outer circle than the inner circle).